# Grails injected services exposed as web methods in cxf

Tags: grails, dependency-injection, jax-ws, cxf

I have a service class that I expose as jaxws using the Grails Cxf plugin. In my service I have to inject another service class which I use in my web services. If I make the service field public I get unnecessary service methods generated like below:

```
retrieveLastRecordUpdateDate
setPricingContractService
retrieveRecordsUpdatedFromDate
retrieveAllRecordsByInsurance
getPricingContractService
```

If I make the field private I cannot inject the service class. How can I both inject the service and not expose it as a web service? Simplified code below:

```
class PricingContractWebService {

static expose = EndpointType.JAX_WS

def pricingContractService // private?

@WebMethod( operationName="retrieveAllRecordsByInsurance" )
@WebResult( name="pricingContractList" )
@XmlElement(name="healthCareCompany", required=true)
List<PricingContractDTO> retrieveAllRecordsByInsurance(@WebParam(partName = "HealthCareCompany", name = "healthCareCompany", ) final HealthCareCompany healthCareCompany) {

    def pricingContractDTOList = []

    pricingContractDTOList
}

@WebMethod( operationName="retrieveLastRecordUpdateDate" )
@WebResult( name="lastUpdateDate" )
Date retrieveLastRecordUpdateDate() {

}

@WebMethod( operationName="retrieveRecordsUpdatedFromDate" )
@WebResult( name="pricingContractList" )
@XmlElement(name="updateDate", required=true)
List<PricingContractDTO> retrieveRecordsUpdatedFromDate(@WebParam(name = "updateDate") final Date date) {

    def pricingContractDTOList = []

    pricingContractDTOList
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should make service endpoint private and add @Autowired before endpoint declaration:

```java
@Autowired
private PricingContractService pricingContractService
```